# How long will tuna salad stay good refrigerated?

Tags: storage-lifetime, refrigerator, tuna

If you make tuna salad, how long is it safe to keep it refrigerated after the tuna is out of the can? I don't like to keep regular raw fish for more than a day but I guess this is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

U.S. Gov't Food Safety Department says 3-5 days at 40º or below (where your fridge should be set).  The site also says that tuna salad does not freeze well.

For more info:  http://www.foodsafety.gov/keep/charts/storagetimes.html